# POSTGRES : ltree ancestors is not ordered

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ltree

I am looking for information but I can't find it in the documentation
I execute a request on my path to ask for the ancestors, I receive all the ancestors but they are all mixed, do you have an idea of my error?

Is it possible to have the order represented directly in the path with ltree?

Thanks in advance

```
select id from magic where path @> '1.38.39.41.42.43.49'

Result : 
49
1
39
38
42
41
43
```

However I would like the following result

```
select id from magic where path @> '1.38.39.41.42.43.49'

Result :
49 
43
42
41
39
38
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found this which is good for me however I don't know if there is anything native to ltree for the order

```
select id from res_partner where path @> '1.38.39.41.42.43.49' order by string_to_array(path::text, '.')::int[] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried order by path? ie something like this:

```
`SELECT * FROM folder WHERE folder.path @> (SELECT path FROM folder as f WHERE f.label = $1) ORDER BY path;
```

`